# Oauth2 playground - Input of scopes in the "input your scopes" box - how?

Tags: scopes, oauth2-playground

How do you input more than one scope in the input your scopes box in the oauth2 playground UI?
I'm trying to generate auth/ refresh tokens using this link:https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

I cannot find the scopes I need in the selection of the API scopes :
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail

Therefore, I am attempting to include this into the "input your scopes box". I am able to include one of these but can enter only one scope in the box. How do I include both?

I have tried the following with no success
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request;https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail

"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail"

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request + https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail

Answer (score 1):

Normally for Google the scopes should be separated by a space:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
```

Facebook uses commas, Instagram uses pluses... Some examples are listed here: https://brandur.org/oauth-scope#google

Unfortunately the OAuth 2.0 spec has not defined multi-scopes clearly so OAuth providers have used different delimiters and consequently the OAuth Playground uses a dumb text field for specifying multiple scopes.

Comment: Thanks, this helps understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue as follows:
a. I made my selections added the client Id, secret etc on the OAuth playground here: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

b. I clicked on the link icon to get the link for the selections made
[image: Link to get Url]

c. Then I edited the URL to include the scopes I want as below (shown in bold):

> https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#step1&apisSelect=
> https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F%2C
> **https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fscript.send_mail%2C https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fscript.external_request**
> &url=myurl&content_type=application%2Fjson&http_method=POST&useDefaultOauthCred=checked&oauthEndpointSelect=Google&oauthAuthEndpointValue=somevalue&oauthTokenEndpointValue=somevalue&oauthClientId=myClientId&oauthClientSecret=mySecret&accessTokenType=bearer...

d. Lastly I pasted this URL in a browser, authorised the APIs and proceeded to get the Auth key.